# Let G be a group. Suppose that x ∈ G has order n ∈ N. Prove that x^n = 1.

Tags: group-theory

I feel like the maths at university is very abstract and sometimes I get lost into the way things are written.(as an example a simple binary operation can be generally noted as a*b or just ab, depending on the writer's idea) 
I guess that can be only fixed by reading lots of proofs?

I think this "abstract" idea applies on the above question from the title as well as I am stuck.

Something I can think about is:
If we have got a group of integers with group operation being multiplication.
I let x=4 then x^n is not 1. So the proof doesn't make sense in this situation for me.

solution:
We have  < x > is a set of size n. The non-negative powers of x are
1, x, x^2, . . . which are not all different because < x > is finite. Let the first repetition be x^m = x^q with 0 ≤ m < q. If m > 0 we can premultiply by x^(−1)
to get an earlier repetition (which is impossible), so m = 0. Thus 1, x, x^2
, . . . are different until a 1 appears as x^q. Therefore q = n. The order of x is n and also x^n = 1.

Comment: You should state the definitions you are using, since for me the definition of an element having order n is precisely the criterion you’re trying to prove.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $x^n=1$ if $|G|=n$?

Comment: I think it is related to that, but the question does not state the cardinality of G.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem only states that if you have got a group then |H| divides |G|, where G is a group and H is its subgroup. How would that relate?

Comment: Note that the subgroup generated by $x$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: That being said, you should edit your question.  The first commenter read it as being "Prove that given that $x$ is an element of a group $G$ where *x is of order n* that $x^n=1$" while it appears you intend this to be "Prove that given that $x$ is an element of a group $G$ where *G is of order n* that $x^n=1$."  As you have written it, you are confusing people about which is the object that we know is of order $n$.

Comment: In a recent edit you say "*Something I can think about is: If we have got a group of integers with group operation being multiplication. I let x=4 then x^n is not 1. So the proof doesn't make sense in this situation for me.*"  Consider the group $\Bbb Z_5^\times$.  You would have $4^4 = 16^2 = 256 =255+1\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.  This comment suggests to me that you are confused as to what "1" is and what "exponentiation" is in a group theoretic sense.  Here "$1$" is in reference to the identity element of the group, whether that happens to be the same as $1$ usually means to us or otherwise.

Comment: That is to say if $\star$ is our group operation, "$1$" is the element such that $1\star x = x\star 1 = x$ for all $x$.  Exponentiation on the other hand is the repeated act of applying the group operation a number of times to an element.  If we have the group operation $\star$, then by $x^n$ we mean $\underbrace{x\star x\star\cdots \star x}_{n~\text{# of times}}$.  In some circumstances our group operation *is* multiplication as we know it usually to mean, but it doesn't have to be.  We just borrow the notation from multiplication for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the definition of order you're using is

> $x$ has order $n$ if (and only if) $\langle x\rangle=\{x^k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ has $n$ elements.

Note that $\langle x\rangle$ is the image of a group homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$, $\varphi(a)=x^a$. The kernel of $\varphi$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is of the form $k\mathbb{Z}$. By the homomorphism theorem,
$$
\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}\cong\langle x\rangle
$$
so $k=n$ by counting elements. Hence $n\in\ker\varphi$, which precisely means that $x^n=1$.

Without homomorphisms, your attempt is quite good, but you're too fast in the conclusion.

You prove correctly that $m=0$, so $x^q=1$. But this only proves that $q\le n$, because the elements $x^0,x^1,\dots,x^{q-1}$ are all distinct.

On the other hand, given any integer $p$, you can write $p=qp'+r$, with $0\le r<q$ and
$$
x^p=(x^q)^{p'}x^r=x^r
$$
so the elements in $\langle x\rangle$ are all of the form $x^r$, with $0\le r<q$. Since there are $n$ elements by assumption, it follows that $n\le q$.

Comment: I can't really understand what does "kernel" mean

Comment: @BurLeXyOOnuTz I added an argument without homomorphisms.

Comment: I m sorry, I forgot to mention that the solution is not mine, and so I don't understand it. Why would we care if there is any repetition and why would we premultiply by x^(-1).